# List all SpatialPoints that fall within gBuffer of another SpatialPoint

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sp

I am wanting to create a data.frame where each row lists a Set{} of SpatialPoints that lie within the buffer of another SpatialPoint. I am using rgeos::gBuffer to create the buffers around each of my points.

Here are some point locations:

```
head(x)
        Lon            Lat
1       839171.2    3861540
2       838852.4    3861143
3       838945.9    3861240
4       824506.8    3865499
5       838851.8    3861160
6       827834.7    3878655
7       888196.5    3929905
8       508308.4    4031569
9       838750.5    3864169
10      983995.6    3993308
```

make a *Spatial object:

```
coordinates(x) <- ~Lon + Lat
```

create a buffer around the points:

```
xbuff <- gBuffer(x, width=1000, byid=TRUE)
```

Now, how do I find the list of points (if any) that fall within each of the 10 buffers created in xbuff?

Answer (score 4):

> how do I find the list of points (if any) that fall within each of the
>   10 buffers

You could do

```
x<-read.table(header=T, text="
Lon            Lat
1       839171.2    3861540
2       838852.4    3861143
3       838945.9    3861240
4       824506.8    3865499
5       838851.8    3861160
6       827834.7    3878655
7       888196.5    3929905
8       508308.4    4031569
9       838750.5    3864169
10      983995.6    3993308")
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
coordinates(x) <- ~Lon + Lat
xbuff <- gBuffer(x, width=1000, byid=TRUE)
over(xbuff, x[1:5,], T)
# $`1`
# [1] 1 2 3 5
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 1 2 3 5
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 1 2 3 5
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 4
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 1 2 3 5
# 
# $`6`
# integer(0)
# 
# $`7`
# integer(0)
# 
# $`8`
# integer(0)
# 
# $`9`
# integer(0)
# 
# $`10`
# integer(0)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the object created from over() a data.frame where each row contains the values from each slice of the list?

Comment: No, because they are not of equal length.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use buffer and intersect operations for this problem. Instead you can compute a distance matrix.

```
x <- matrix(c(839171.2, 838852.4, 838945.9, 824506.8, 838851.8, 827834.7, 888196.5, 508308.4, 838750.5, 983995.6, 3861540, 3861143, 3861240, 3865499, 3861160, 3878655, 3929905, 4031569, 3864169, 3993308), ncol=2)

library(raster)
d <- pointDistance(x, lonlat=FALSE)
diag(d) <- NA
r <- apply(d, 1, function(i) which(i < 1000))
r
```

This should be computationally more efficient. However, if you have many points the distance matrix can become very (too) large. In that case you can loop over chunks of the data.

```
chunksize <- 5
nr <- nrow(x)
s  <- seq(1, nr, chunksize)
r  <- vector(length=nr, mode='list')
for (i in 1:length(s)) {
    start <- s[i]
    end  <- min(nr, start + chunksize)
    y <- x[start:end, ,drop=FALSE]
    d <- pointDistance(y, x, lonlat=FALSE)
##  d[cbind(1:nrow(y), start:end)] <- NA
    r[start:end] <- apply(d, 1, function(i) which(i < 1000))
}
```

This includes the focal points. You can set the 'diagonal' to `NA` to avoid that, but that can lead to errors if there are no points within range, so I commented hat out.